# Only able to call Cast and OfType on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

In a library I am using I have am having issues calling any LINQ methods other than those on IEnumerable. I have a class hierarchy as follows (naming is slightly strange, since it is obfuscated from internal code)

```
Item : GeneralObject

ItemCollection : GenericCollection<ItemCollection, Item>

GenericCollection<TCollection, TItem> : GeneralObjectCollection, IEnumerable<TItem>
    where TCollection : GenericCollection<TCollection, TItem>
    where TItem : GeneralObject

GeneralObjectCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable<GeneralObject>
```

As can be seen, `IEnumerable` is in ItemCollection's class hierarchy twice, so there are two `GetEnumerator` methods, one which provides a `GeneralObject` and one which provides an `Item`.

When I look at the class definition provided via metadata in VS2019, each class that implements `IEnumerable<TItem>` also shows as implemented `IEnumerable`.

With this setup, I am unable to call most LINQ methods like Select, Where, etc, on any ItemCollection instances, and can only do those on `IEnumerable`. It looks like it should clearly support methods on `IEnumerable<T>` as well, but for some reason I have to cast it first.

Both casting to `IEnumerable<TItem>` and using `.Cast<TItem>`, work but these seem like they should be unnecessary.

Code sample below. The second example would not compile:

```
private ItemCollection GetItemsFromDatabase(string query)
{
    // Internal logic.
}

List<Item> newItemList = ((IEnumerable<Item>)GetItemsFromDatabase(itemQuery))
                                        .Select(x => new ItemInfo(x.Name, x.Id, x.Guid)).ToList();
```

and

```
private ItemCollection GetItemsFromDatabase(string query)
{
    // Internal logic.
}

List<Item> newItemList = GetItemsFromDatabase(itemQuery).Select(x => new ItemInfo(x.Name, x.Id, x.Guid)).ToList();
```

The error is:
'ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I am using LINQ elsewhere in this file with no issue, so it is not a matter of providing the right using or an actual assembly reference.

Comment: Have you referenced `System.Linq` namespace? can you please post the code too so people can have a better idea. And what is the error you get when you try to use those methods?

Comment: _"somewhat obfuscated and incomplete as it is internal code"_ - read [ask] and create a [mre]. Do you have `using System.Linq` in your usings? Also, if it works when casting, what is the actual return type of `GetItemsFromDatabase()`?

Comment: Yes I have System.Linq in the namespace. Like I said I can use Cast and OfType which are extension methods and so System.Linq is being properly imported. This is not a case of having the right usings.

Comment: Can you show the _exact_ problem you face when trying to use the other extensions? There are two things I'd expect: the generic interfaces are probably implemented _explicitly_, needing you to call it like `((IEnumerable<TItem>)collection).Select(...)`, or the compiler cannot resolve the correct extensions because it can't decide if you mean `Select<TItem>` or `Select<GeneralObject>`...

Comment: @MatiasGrioni In that case you need to provide details and code here so people can reproduce and maybe correct the error.

Comment: I've added some code examples to show the exact line in question. I think that with the class hierarchy should be enough. The main point in the class hierarchy that I wanted to show is that IEnumerable is seen twice, with a different generic parameter each time.

Comment: @RenéVogt The code does have to cast, or use .Cast as you say. The class hierarchy explicitly implements the generic interface as well, IEnumerable<TItem> rather than just IEnumerable, but it comes up in two different paths, so I'm not sure if that causes issues with extension method resolution.

Comment: What does `GetItemsFromDatabase` return though? Show us the signature of that method and give us the **exact** error message that you are seeing.

Comment: Again, create a [mre] (if you suspect the multiple implementation of the same interface, then create a class implementing `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable<int>` or whatever), and read the compiler errors when calling Linq extension methods on it. Then research those.

Comment: You still did not post any error message.

Comment: @RenéVogt @DavidG I have added an error message. Thanks for the reminder that had slipped my mind. While the code examples are just the skeleton I think it provides information to understand the issue. A class that would normally implement `IEnumerable<T>` would have no issues with calling `Select`.

Comment: Can you confirm you have `using System.Linq;` in this file? Other than that, the question makes no sense and I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have fixed up the type hierarchy as well, as I noticed it was not super specific. Thanks for the patience!

Comment: @DavidG `using System.Linq` is in the file. I did not provide a full fledged reproducible example, but I think the details are there to understand that this is a normal class that extends IEnumerable<T>, albeit twice with two different type parameters, that does not properly resolve extension methods on IEnumerable<T> for any type parameter. I assume this is the crux of the issue, but I cannot find much info on why that might be.

Comment: It probably has to do with implicit vs explicit interface implementation. I bet you have an implicit interface impl of IEnumerable and explicit of IEnumerable<T>, hence casting is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly conjectured, the problem arises because of ambiguities discovered during type inference. When you say:

```
class Ark : IEnumerable<Turtle>, IEnumerable<Giraffe> 
{ ... }
```

and then you say

```
Ark ark = whatever;
ark.Select(x => whatever);
```

somehow the compiler has to know whether you meant `a.Select<Turtle, Result>` or `a.Select<Giraffe, Result>`.  Under no circumstances will C# try to guess that you meant `a.Select<Animal, Result>` or `a.Select<object, Result>` because *that was not one of the choices provided*.  C# only makes choices from available types, and the available types are `IEnumerable<Turtle>` and `IEnumerable<Giraffe>`.

If there is no basis upon which to make a decision then type inference fails. Since we only got to extension methods after all other overload resolution attempts failed, we're probably going to fail overload resolution at this point.

There are many ways to make this work, but all of them involve somehow giving C# a hint about what you meant. The easiest way is

```
ark.Select<Turtle, Result>(x => whatever);
```

But you can also do

```
ark.Select((Turtle x) => whatever);
```

Or

```
((IEnumerable<Turtle>)ark).Select(x => whatever);
```

Or

```
(ark as IEnumerable<Turtle>).Select(x => whatever);
```

Those are all good. You deduced that this compiles:

```
ark.Cast<Turtle>().Select(x => whatever); 
// NEVER DO THIS IN THIS SCENARIO
// USE ANY OF THE OTHER TECHNIQUES, NEVER THIS ONE
```

**Do you see why it is dangerous**? Do not proceed until you understand why this is probably wrong.  Reason it through.

---

In general, it's a dangerous practice to implement a type that implements two of "the same" generic interfaces because *very weird things can happen*. The language and the runtime were not designed to handle this sort of unification elegantly. Consider for example how covariance works; what happens if we cast `ark` to `IEnumerable<Animal>`?   See if you can figure it out; then try it and see if you were right.

Unfortunately, you are in an even worse position; what if you instantiate `GenericCollection<TCollection, TItem>` such that `TItem` is `GeneralObject`? **Now you have implemented `IEnumerable<GeneralObject>` twice!** That's really confusing to users and the CLR does not like that at all.

The better practice is to make `Ark` implement neither interface, but rather expose two methods, one which returns turtles and one which returns giraffes. You should strongly consider doing the same in your class. A better design would be to make `GenericCollection<TCollection, TItem>` not implement `IEnumerable<TItem>` but rather to have a property `IEnumerable<TItem> Items { get { ... } }`.

With that design, you can then do `collection.Select` to get general objects, or `collection.Items.Select` to get items, and the problem goes away.

Comment: I would have expected the compiler to know to pick `Turtle` for `Select` when this interface gets implicitly implemented and `Giraffe` explicitly. Feels like a shortcoming of the compiler.

Comment: @dfhwze: That's a reasonable conjecture, but wrong; it's wrong in an interesting way. The fundamental problem is: there is no such thing as an implicitly or explicitly implemented interface. Suppose we have `interface I { void M(); void N(); }` and `class C : I { public void M(){} void I.N(){}}`. Is `I` implemented explicitly or not, in your opinion? By examining this case we see that there is no such thing as an explicitly implemented *interface*, only an explicitly implemented *member*.

Comment: @dfhwze: Since the explicitness of an implementation is a decision that the implementor makes about particular members, there is no basis upon which to choose between two interfaces. Besides, why should the implementation choices matter? The question is "if we cast this type to some interface, what implementation of that interface do we get?" Why should that choice depend on how the implementor chose to implement the interfaces?

Comment: I get your point, it's finegrained at the level of a member. So when we apply this to the OP, what if both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<Giraffe>` are explicitly implemented members, and `IEnumerable<Turtle>` implicitly? The compiler should be able to determine that `.Select()` can only pick that last one.

Comment: @dfhwze: First, why should that matter? Second, suppose I make a change in my class from making an implementation explicit to implicit; should that change overload resolution? That seems like an unexpected breaking change.

Comment: @dfhwze: Third, you say that "the compiler should be able to determine this", but the implicitness or explicitness of an interface implementation is a fact about *C# source code*. **What if we don't have the source code**? What if the class is in some other assembly; what are you going to do then? What if the class isn't even written in C#, and is written in a language that does not have the concept of "implicit interface implementation"? Not every language makes that distinction.

Comment: To me this falls in the same category as the `new` operator. You define which method is called by deciding the declared type.

Comment: Compiler is wrong, the runtime is a better choice of words.

Comment: @dfhwze: But ultimately: the C# language is not designed to make guesses when code looks wrong. It's designed to tell you that you have an ambiguity and that your code is probably wrong. If you prefer languages that try to guess what you meant and thereby hide bugs, try Visual Basic; it does a good job of that.  C# developers consistently tell the development team that they want *less guessing* from the compiler.

Comment: I agree you want to avoid ambigious situations and have a clear design. But that is no reason (in my opinion) to treat this particular situation as ambigious. Since only one such member is implicitly implemented, it should be the standard. For me this is a core part of polymorphism.

Comment: @dfhwze: I still don't understand what you mean by "implicitly implemented" with respect to an interface; nor do I understand what this has to do with polymorphism in your mind. Just saying "polymorphism" is unhelpful because this example has three kinds of polymorphism: ad hoc polymorphism, parametric polymorphism, and nominal subtype polymorphism, *and they are in conflict with each other in this example*. You're saying that nominal subtype polymorphism should win based on some criterion about the declaration; I'm saying that in a conflicting situation, *make it an error*.

Comment: question asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875750/interface-conflict-resolution-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

For others who have a similar issue, the issue arises from extension method resolution.

When I call select with template parameters, for example:

```
List<Item> newItemList = GetItemsFromDatabase(itemQuery).Select<Item, ItemInfo>(x => new ItemInfo(x.Name, x.Id, x.Guid)).ToList();
```

the code properly compiles.

It seems like when resolving the method call, after exhausting the instance methods, it cannot resolve any extension method either when just `Select(...)` is used. My guess is that `Select` is obviously present, but it does not resolve  because of ambiguity in the type definition, both `IEnumerable<GeneralObject>` or `IEnumerable<Item>`, and inability for the inference engine to resolve types for a call to Select. And so no extension method matches against `ItemCollection` and the final error says that select is not defined, rather than specifying that types cannot be inferred for the extension method call and need to be specified.

Comment: Are you happy with this solution or should I have a go at it?

Comment: This solution is fine. From the looks of it, it ultimately looks like an issue with the C# compiler giving a strange error, which led me astray. I do not think there would be a nicer solution given that the type hierarchy cannot be changed.

Comment: Your guess is correct; see my answer for details.  I agree that the error message could be better; I am sorry about that. It was my intention to improve this error message and I did not get around to it before leaving Microsoft in 2012.

Comment: That said, I note that this is a difficult error message to devise an algorithm to detect reliably, for a great many reasons starting with *the scenario is rare*.